# What can cause Sitecore web[data] cache to not be evicted on publish

Tags: publishing, content-delivery, caching

I have a strange problem with my distributed CM/CD Sitecore 8.2 environment.

Certain items and their children are published programmatically on a schedule after an automated update process. The update process deletes old children and creates new children with new IDs. This means the publish operation needs to delete the old children and create the new children on the CD at publish time.

The way these are published is using the following API call:

```
PublishManager.PublishItem
(
    item: parentItem,
    targets: dbTargetArray,
    languages: langArray,
    deep: true,
    compareRevisions: true, // smart publish (false for republish) 
    publishRelatedItems: false
 );
```

- The items and their children get correctly published.
- When pulling out the child items on the CD, some come through as null/non existent, even though we know they are there.

  - E.g. `parentItem.Axes.SelectItems("./somechild/*[@@templatekey='sometemplate']"`
- If we clear the `web[data]` cache and also the `web[items]` cache (which sits on top of `web[data]`) on the CD the problem is immediately resolved.
- If we manually republish (via the publish ribbon in Content Editor) the item, the problem is resolved.

With all this in mind, **why and/or how could this happen**? It's like the `web[data]` cache is "stuck" thinking the child items don't exist and therefore returns null each time, which then has the knock-on effect of putting null into the `web[items]` cache. Clear these 2 caches and it hits the database to get the real data, repopulates the caches and we're back in business.

Sitecore is supposed to evict items from the caches as and when they get updated, added, deleted, etc. by the publish process, but it's like it's somehow not evicting cache entries for the children that are "not found".

Comment: Does this issue happens everytime the custom publish is triggered?

Comment: @HishaamNamooya Yes pretty much. We publish approx 600 parent items, and of those probably about 30-40% have the caching issue, but different 30-40% each time. I presume it is related to certain pages getting hit on the CD during the publish operation, so it's never the same items each time, but never none.

Comment: i would say you need to check your configuration , check the following article as it is a good way to start with: https://himynameistim.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/sitecore-html-cache-not-clearing-on-publish/

Comment: Have you checked the size of your eventqueue. The item cache clear is done through the eventqueue to the CD servers. is the evenqueue read properly?

Comment: Which version of 8.2 are you on? There were several updates which had publishing issues specifically related to deleted items, from what I remember.

Comment: @JayS interesting point. We're on Sitecore.NET 8.2 (rev. 161221). You got a link/release notes for that specific issue(s)? Thanks

Comment: Also... After some trial and error I can confirm that it is specifically the Sitecore `web[data]` cache that is the culprit (and consequently the `web[items]` cache, which sits on top of it). I cleared `web[items]` manually - no luck. Then cleared `web[data]` AND `web[items]` and the problem was resolved. I'll add this to the question for clarity.

Comment: @NaimAlkouki I specifically stated it's **NOT** the HTMLCache so your comment is not helpful, sorry.

Comment: @KlausPetersen good thinking. I'm not entirely sure how big the eventqueue gets during the update/publish process as it runs overnight when everyone is asleep, then the eventqueue is cleared down as normal. I'd need some tool to see the size of it during the operation. Any ideas?

Comment: @KlausPetersen Currently the size is < 500 rows in the Web db and 11,000 in the Core db. We have a SQL job which clears down any entries older than 2 hours.

Comment: I saw similar issue before for one client using the same version 161221 change the "Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits" setting to false solved his issue. try that

Comment: @NaimAlkouki we already have Cache limits enabled with `<setting name="Caching.DisableCacheSizeLimits" value="false"/>`

Comment: can you check the logs for memory usage on CM?

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of 8.2 had some publishing issues:

- https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/136794
- https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/631685

There were a batch of publishing issues resolved in 8.2 updates 4 & 5:

- https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update4/Release%20Notes
- https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/82/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2082%20Update5/Release%20Notes

I would recommend an upgrade to a more recent update of 8.2 or to contact support to see if there hotfixes you could apply.